# Pandas: index of max value for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Pandas DataFrame, `df`, looks like this:

```
parameter1   parameter2   value

1            1            0.1
             2            0.2

2            1            0.6
             2            0.3
```

`value` is the result of a `groupby(['parameter1','parameter2']).mean()` on another `DataFrame`. Now, I can find the maximum value of `value` for each value of `parameter1` using

```
df.max(level='parameter1')
```

However, I need to find the corresponding value of `parameter2` for this maximum value. It seems `df.idxmax()` does not support `level=`, so how can I do this instead?

Answer (score 4):

I eventually found a trick:

Groupby on level 0 (parameter1) and apply `idxmax()` and get the values:

```
v = df.groupby(level=0).idxmax().values
v
array([[(1, 2)],
       [(2, 1)]], dtype=object)
```

This is what `df.idxmax(level=0)` would give if implemented.

So `v` contains the index giving the max value for that level. So you can get the real values with:

```
df.loc[v.ravel()]

                       value
parameter1 parameter2       
1          2             0.2
2          1             0.6
```

and finally get the value of parameter2 corresponding to max values:

```
df.loc[v.ravel()].index.values[1]
(2, 1)
```

HTH

Answer (score 4):

A nice way would be

```
df.unstack().idxmax(axis=1)
```

Unstacking the dataframe gives a dataframe with `parameter_1` as the column index.

Answer (score 0):

On option is to override the idxmax() function :

```
def idxmax(x):
    return x.idxmax()[0]
```

and then use `agg()` method for aggregation :

```
df.groupby(['parameter1','parameter2']).agg(idxmax)
```