# How to compare the data and choose the maximum one from multiIndex dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How to compare the data and choose the maximum one from multiIndex dataframe in pandas?

For example:

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz','foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),np.array(['AA', 'AB', 'AC','BA', 'BB', 'CA', 'CB', 'DA', 'DB'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(9, 1), index=arrays)
df
```

out

```
         0
bar AA   1.740325
    AB   2.017906
    AC  -0.873244
baz BA  -1.761734
    BB   0.467648
foo CA   0.740907
    CB  -0.322276
qux DA   0.607481
    DB  -0.460324
```

Finally, I want to choose like this:

```
   1    2   0
0  bar  AB  2.017906
1  baz  BB  0.467648
2  foo  CA  0.740907
3  qux  DA  0.607481
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution should be simplify by specify column for check `max` values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
np.random.seed(234)
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz','foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),np.array(['AA', 'AB', 'AC','BA', 'BB', 'CA', 'CB', 'DA', 'DB'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(9, 1), index=arrays)
print (df)

               0
bar AA  0.818792
    AB -1.043551
    AC  0.350901
baz BA  0.921578
    BB -0.087382
foo CA -3.128885
    CB -0.969733
qux DA  0.934666
```

---

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)[0].idxmax()]
print (df)
               0
bar AA  0.818792
baz BA  0.921578
foo CB -0.969733
qux DA  0.934666
```

Answer (score 1):

Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097746/pandas-index-of-max-value-for-each-group)

```
v = df.groupby(level=0).idxmax().values
df.loc[v.ravel()]
```